# HTML5 Spinning Logo

Tags: jquery, html, css, graphical-logo

I am trying to achieve a logo that spins around on a slight delay after page load. At the moment I am using this code pretty much exactly, however at the moment it works when the user flicks the image, as i said, I just want it to spin on load.

Total newbie at JS, I would do a jsFiddle, but am having trouble to get it to work at all in there. Can anyone help me out?

http://925html.com/files/html5logo/ < Current Code

Thanks,
Red

Comment: here's the fiddle for anyone who wants it http://jsfiddle.net/ngDcg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you can do this:

```
YUI().use('transition', function (Y){
                    Y.one('#logo').transition({
                        transform    : 'rotateY(' + 360 + 'deg)',
                        duration    : 2,
                        easing        : 'ease-out'
                    }, function(){
                        this.setStyle('webkitTransform', 'rotateY(0deg)');
                    });

            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HFFDR/

Comment: @Red your welcome :) but honestly I have no clue how this works :P I've never used YUI before.  But I am glad this solves your question :)